# Will Setting open_basedir in an .htaccess file completely limit a PHP scripts directory access?

Tags: php, .htaccess, security, open-basedir

My PHP script uses $_POST['fileUrl']; to retrieve a file for the user, which I believe poses a security threat because anyone could append "../../" etc to the fileUrl to gain access to other files on my server.

I need to find the best (most secure) way to limit files my script can access to a specific directory. From what I've read setting the open_basedir flag will limit my script's access to the path specified.

script.php

```
$fileUrl = $_POST['fileUrl'];
$content = chunk_split(base64_encode(file_get_contents($fileUrl)));
```

.htaccess

```
php_flag open_basedir  "var/www/vhosts/mydomain.com/php_can_only_access_files_in_this_directory/"
```

Is there a better way to do this? Is this script completely secure from accessing folders outside the open_basedir?

Comment: Shouldn't `var/www/vhosts` start with a slash: `/var/www/vhosts` so it is interpreted as an absolute file path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to avoid people performing directory traversal attacks by using ../../ in the file name you would be better off calling basename on the user supplied input to strip it down to a filename only.

See https://www.php.net/basename for more details.

It is worth noting that the open_basedir flag only affects functions that check for it, in the past there have been several cases where php functions ignore the open_basedir flag, particularly in extensions such as imagemagick. Hence you should rather rely on secure coding practices and file permissions to restrict access to files.

Answer (score 1):

`s/php_flag/php_value/`.

php_flag doesn't work consistently for open_basedir, when it does work at all.  php_flag is for flags , php_value is for values . "path/:another/path/" is a value.